# Prove an altered p-norm is increasing

Tags: real-analysis

$x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ Prove that $g(p)=[(1/n)(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)]^{1/p}$ is increasing on the interval $(0, \infty)$, and find $\lim_{p\to\infty}g(p)$

I find this is extremely difficult.  I suppose I could use the first derivative to show that it's increasing, but I can't connect it to the Holder inequality, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < p < q < \infty$, then $\frac{q}{p} > 1$; Holder's inequality thus gives

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^p \le \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n 1\right)^{1 - \frac{p}{q}}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n (|x_k|^p)^{\frac{q}{p}}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} = n^{1-\frac{p}{q}}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^q\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^p \le \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^q\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}$$

Taking $p$th roots results in the inequality $g(p) \le g(q)$. Hence $g$ is increasing.

Try to show that $$\lim_{p \to \infty} g(p) = \max\{|x_1|,\ldots, |x_n|\}$$